# How to position text on node in cytoscape.js

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

I am using [cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) to create graph with nodes. I want to position node's content below that node so that arrow direction is clearly visible. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-halign` and `text-valign`.
http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style/properties

Comment: Hi maxkfranz, I have used 'text-valign' property and it is working correctly but i want to place node's content some pixels value away (e.g.,5 px) from its current bottom position. How can i do this? Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there any property for set margin under the node text ?

Comment: Updated link: https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels
... I'd also like finer-grained label placement.  :-)